# How can I make sure that I all decimal places even if 0 are shown

Tags: python

my_rounded_list = [ round(elem, 2) for elem in my_list ]

for item in my_rounded_list:
print(" ", item[0], "|", item[1], "|", item[2], "|")

How can I show all decimal places as part of my list

Comment: You can use [fancier output formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting:

```
print("   x    | sin(x) | cos(x)")
print("--------|--------|--------")

for item in my_list:
    print(" |".join([f'{x: 7.3f}' for x in item]))
```

Output:

```
   x    | sin(x) | cos(x)
--------|--------|--------
  0.000 |  0.000 |  1.000
  0.314 |  0.309 |  0.951
  0.628 |  0.588 |  0.809
  0.942 |  0.809 |  0.588
  1.257 |  0.951 |  0.309
  1.571 |  1.000 |  0.000
  1.885 |  0.951 | -0.309
  2.199 |  0.809 | -0.588
  2.513 |  0.588 | -0.809
  2.827 |  0.309 | -0.951
  3.142 |  0.000 | -1.000
```